# redux-forms/ FOCUS / BLUR / CHANGE doesn't work

Tags: javascript, redux-form

In my code when click to open dropdown show => redux-form/FOCUS only  then after other click in whatever place (choosing countries or outside the dropdown) show redux-form/BLUR.It should show FOCUS first and after milliseconds BLUR. And when click on again should CHANGE. Now doesn't change (probably) because BLUR it has not come after FOCUS...  How I can do that BLUR come automatically after FOCUS? And after that when I click on select item redux-form/CHANGE?Thank you very much for whatever help

```
export const renderSelectField = ({ input, maxHeight, fullWidth, label, style, meta: { touched, error }, children }) => (
  <SelectField floatingLabelText={label}
    fullWidth={fullWidth}
    style={!style ? { width: '100%', margin: 0 } : style}
    errorText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    children={children}
    maxHeight={maxHeight}
    onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
  />
)
```